# Site container in split-screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I don't know what I tell you about this problem. I will show you a image.

[image]

This website container must be 1000px. But left section's background color and right section's background color should go to end of the screen. But left section and right section's background color different from each other.
I don't want to use javascript for this. 
Is there any way to how do this in css.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

if it is just about colors, then multiple image or gradient can be used. gradient will require background-size.

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, gray, gray) center repeat-y, linear-gradient(to left, pink, pink) right repeat-y, linear-gradient(to left, yellow, yellow);
  background-size: 400px 1px, 50%, auto;
}
p {width:400px;margin:auto;}
/* 400px and a single tag for demo snippet*/
```

```html
<p>play in full page & resize window.</p>
```

codepen to play with : 100px width bg http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdEOZE

---

note , multiple gradients or image lays under previous. The first shows on top.